# Can't locate ./uploads folder when uploading file to Express JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have project with the following (simplified) structure:

```
-app
    -uploads
    -client
           - dropzone.js
    -server.js
```

I'm trying to upload a file by using `dropzone js`, `Express JS` and `React JS`. However, each time I drop a file in the dropzone box, I get this in the `console.log`:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/uploads/ 404 (Not Found)

Not found
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /uploads/</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

The location of the `./uploads` folder is correct, and I'm confused why I cannot do a `POST` request from my React component to Express. Any help would be appreciated!

The `React` component has this:

```
class Dropbox extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            selectedFile: [],
            description: ''
        }
    }

    onDrop = () => {
        const { selectedFile, description } = this.state;
        let formData = new FormData();
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        formData.append('description', description);
        formData.append('selectedFile', selectedFile);

        xhr.open('POST', './uploads/', true);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                console.log(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }

        xhr.send(formData);
    }

    render() {
        const selectedFile = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}>
                    <p>Drop PDF here</p>
                </Dropzone>
                <p>{this.state.selectedFile.map(f => <li>{f.name}</li>)}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And my `server.js` file is:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid-v4');
const app = express();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const newFilename = `${uuidv4()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null, newFilename);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post('/', upload.single('selectedFile'), (req, res) => {
    res.send();
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: You haven't set up a route to handle `/uploads`. Your POST action is going to hit your server at `/uploads` first and doesn't care about the file structure of the system it's running on. Your server needs a route to know how to handle it.

Comment: To go along with what @alephtwo said, you could just change your `app.post('/', ()=>{...})` to `app.post('/uploads', ()=>{...});`

Comment: @alephtwo Post your comment as an answer.  I'm pretty sure that it is correct or at least the root of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set up a route to handle /uploads. Your POST action is going to hit your server at /uploads first and doesn't care about the file structure of the system it's running on. Your server needs a route to know how to handle it.

I think your intent is to use your `/` route to upload, so you have a couple of options:

- Update your route to be `app.post('/uploads'...)`
- Update your POST to hit `/` instead of `/uploads`

Either one should take care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @alephtwo! The responseStatus is now '200 OK'. A quick question - should the dropped files actually pop up in the uploads folder? Because they aren't. I'm running express and react concurrently, maybe that's why?

Comment: React and Express have nothing to do with it - your response handler function receives a post and you have to do something with it, which probably involves some calls to `fs` to actually create the file on disk.